# Return argument doesn't work — gives me weird error

Tags: c, string, types, return, printf

This is a simple program that should create a substring from a string, then it should return the substring as something that can be printed out.
It's actually an exercise and only the substring function can be changed. The problem is that I can't find a return type that doesn't spark all kinds of warnings and errors.

How should I change the return type?

```
static void panic(const char *serror)
{
    printf("%s", serror);
    exit(1);
}

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr;
    if (size == 0)
        panic("Size is 0!\n");
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (!ptr)
        panic("No mem left!\n");
    return ptr;
}

static char *substring(const char *str, off_t pos, size_t len)
{
    char out [len];
    int index;

    for(index = 0; index < (pos + len); index++)
    {
        if(index >= pos && index < (pos + len))
        {
        out[index - pos] = str[index];
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *foo = "Nicht\n";
    char *bar = substring(foo, 2, 3);
    printf("%s", bar);
    free(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that error messages should be printed to `stderr`, rather than to standard output.  However, a function like `panic()` is a good tool to have in your toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoked two *undefine behavior* by

- dereferencing a pointer `bar` that points at already vanished local variable.
- passing a non-`NULL` pointer which doesn't point at buffer allocated via `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

Also note that

- You have to terminate the string by adding null character.
- Your loop is not efficient.

corrected code:

```
static char *substring(const char *str, off_t pos, size_t len)
{
    char *out = xmalloc(len + 1);
    int index;

    for(index = pos; index < (pos + len); index++)
    {
        out[index - pos] = str[index];
    }
    out[len] = '\0';

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that stops the error, but it still doesn't print anything.