# Function allocates always to the same address, and the variable doesn't change

Tags: c, function, pointers, return, memory-address

The function `f` allocates its result always to the same address, that makes the `main()` function always print out the same result, how do I make the function allocate the variable an another address and `free` them.

```
int *f(int a) {
    int b = 2 * a;
    return &b;
}

int main(void) {
    int *p4, *p8;

    p4 = f(4);
    p8 = f(8);

    printf("p4: %i / p8: %i\n", *p4, *p8);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380758/c-error-function-returns-address-of-local-variable

Answer (score 4):

The function `f` does not allocate anything, it returns the address of a local variable with automatic storage.  Accessing data via this pointer invokes undefined behavior as soon as `b` goes out of scope, when `f` returns.  The compiler should be able to detect such a silly bug.

To allocate memory, you should use `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *f(int a) {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    if (p != NULL)
        *p = 2 * a;
    return p;
}

int main(void) {
    int *p4 = f(4);
    int *p8 = f(8);

    if (p4 != NULL && p8 != NULL) {
        printf("p4: %i / p8: %i\n", *p4, *p8);
    }
    free(p4);
    free(p8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For OP, needs a "and `free` them." part.

Comment: @chux: indeed it is good practice to `free` all allocated memory, although not strictly required when the program exits.

Comment: OP is [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35691275/2410359) with accepting.  Consider [It's okay. Once.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/2410359)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare b as static ore better yet,declare b as parameter in f function. You could do something like this

```
static bool f(int a,int *b)
{
    if(NULL == b)
    {
        return false;
    }
    *b = a * 2;
    return true;
}
```

It is better to write functions that return nothing(void) or a boolean to let you know if everything went fine and use pointers to modify data and reduce the use of the stack. Most safety-critical standards adopt this rule.

Comment: Neither of these options address the OP's question: *how do I make the function allocate the variable an another address and free them.*

Comment: Agree detection of success or failure of allocation is a good thing.  Yet my experience with "safety-critical standards" disallowed memory allocation altogether.

Comment: Since he only needs a variable,there's no reasono to use malloc() and consequently free(),so i posted a possible (simple) solution to his problem that does not require the use of the functions mentioned before.From MISRA/C: "Rule 20.4 (required): Dynamic heap memory allocation shall not be used."